# how to write a Node.js file that can be called from command line as well as 'require()'d from other files?

Tags: node.js, command-line, require

I want to write a Node.js source file (`myCode.js`) in which there is a function say `foo(arg1, arg2,..)`, such that I can ..

```
$ node ./myCode.js arg1 arg2
```

as well as

```
// myOtherCode.js
var foo = require('./mycode')
```

Is it possible? Currently I have a small bunch of files like these and they all are coded like

```
return (
    function foo() {
        //...
    }
)()
```

which I call from the node command line like

```
$ node ./myCode.js arg1 agr2
```

But now I want to string them together in a single javascript that will be called from commandline with 'node' or 'npm script' (so all functionality from different files will need to be 'require()d'). But I also want to retain the ability to run them individually if it need to be.

I understand that when called from shell prompt, the arg1, arg2 will become argv[2], argv[3] and so on,  and when 'require()'d, they would be function arguments.

This probably also means that I need to pass arguments to 'require()'? How can I accomplish this?

[Using Node.js 8.x [LTS] version, so cannot use export/import syntax]

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible . you have to use process.argv to retreive the passed parameters

for example if we need to console the string "hello" we have to create a  file 
"fileName.js" that contain this code :

```
 let firstArgument = process.argv[_.indexOf(process.argv, '--firstArgument') + 1];
 console.log(firstArgument);
```

and then execute this in the terminal

```
 node ./fileName.js --firstArgument varValue
```

Answer (score 2):

It's conventional to have different entry points for command-line and programmatic package use. A usual recipe for parsing CLI arguments in Node.js is `process.argv.slice(2)`, since `node` and script name are the first 2 arguments.

For package-level executable script, `foo` function is exported from *index.js* entry point:

```
module.exports = function foo(arg1, arg2) { /* ... */ };
```

Considering that `foo` expects string arguments, *bin/index.js* CLI executable script can be as concise as:

```
require('..')(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

Both can be specified in package.json:

```
"main": "index.js",
"bin": { "foo": "bin/index.js" }
```

> This probably also means that I need to pass arguments to 'require()'? How can I accomplish this?

There is no way to pass them to `require`. If a script needs to accept arguments programmatically, this means that it should be wrapped with factory function that accepts arguments.

A quick-and-dirty fix is to pass arguments to CLI executable script through `process.argv`. For instance, a helper function that allows to invoke executable scripts with dynamic arguments:

```
const decache = require('decache');

function loadCliModule(name, ...args) {
    decache(name);
    const originalArgv = process.argv;
    process.argv = [...process.argv.slice(2), ...args];
    const binModule = require(name);
    process.argv = originalArgv;
    return binModule;
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
const foo = invokeCliModule(require.resolve('./foo'), 'bar'); // foo expects process.argv[2]
```

Notice that due to how `decache` works, it decaches only the module that was loaded. If submodules make use of `process.argv`, this should be handled accordingly.

This shouldn't be done in production because the approach is hacky but it's perfectly suitable for testing.

A natural limitation is that arguments that are passed from CLI are strings, so a function should contain boilerplate code to convert them to expected data types (numbers, booleans, etc). For this reason it's preferable to separate programmatic and CLI entry points.

If there's a necessity to call a lot of scripts like that, this may be actual problem, and the solution is to create single CLI executable script that processes arguments with a library like `yargs` and calls functions from other files based on that.

Comment: I'm trying to convert  bunch of shell scripts to equiv. Node.js files. The scripts are for testing another software and are run via a controlling/master script, but can be run individually as well. My Node.js files are now in a state where each is run individually `(node <file> arg1 arg2)`, but I wish to extend them to run via an assert library like `tape` wherein I would need to `require()` them. Each one will `return` `OK` or `NOTOK`. So the same file needs to behave like a function.

Comment: That's important detail that isn't covered in the question. It's perfectly acceptable to use a hack to invoke such modules for testing purposes. I updated the answer.