# Call index.js with arguments from mocha test suite

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a `index.js` that takes some arguments.

```
// parameters
var outFile = process.argv[2] || (() => {throw "missing argument outFile";})();
var templateName = process.argv[3] || (() => {throw "missing argument templateName";})();
```

Now I want to test calling index.js with arguments, not to test the function itself but to the argument validations.

it there a way to write a mocha suite like this

```
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Wenn calling index.js', function() {
  describe('with arguments arg1 arg2', function() {
    it('should should fail because of "missing argument outFile"', function() {
       ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't really get your question. What is preventing you from writing the above test suites?

Comment: @Lewis I am fairly new to javascript. `require('../src/index.js');` would directly execute the code. I am thinking of something like this `invokeScript('../src/index.js', [arg1, arg2]);`

Comment: Then you can check the args validations before requiring that index file. `argsValid && require('../src/index.js')`

Comment: @Lewis propably the problem is that you have to populate `process.argv`, so parameters should be passed via CLI (not only one set, but different combinations). I'd try mocking `process.argv`. As a sidenote: you can call `require` with parameters, but they won't be stored in `process.argv`

Comment: As for invokeScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51711957/3731501 .

Comment: @estus, thanks. Looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process` is global variable in nodejs apps, so you should be able to set desired parameters in your tests. You can reset `process.argv` using `afterEach` hook.

```
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Wenn calling index.js', function() {
  describe('with arguments arg1 arg2', function() {

    afterEach(function(){
      process.argv = process.argv.slice(0,2);
    });

    it('should should fail because of "missing argument outFile"', function() {
      process.argv[3] = "param templateName";
      require("path/to/index.js");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Easy solution, too, didn't think of this.